# How to format historical dates in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm compiling list of historical events spanning from ancient history till current day in Excel 2016. Because I love the filtering and sorting capability of tables in Excel. The problem is that we don't know the exact dates (Date column in my table) for lot of events and there are others for which we know the precise dates. Here are some sample dates from my table: `198 BC, somwhere between 2000BC - 1500BC, 10 AD, 1240-55 AD, 11 Oct 1723 AD.`

I've split Date into two columns `Starting Date` and `Ending Date`, which took care of the problem of ranges in dates. But how to deal with `BC` & `AD` dates and how can I reconcile precise dates and just years, with out loosing the capability of sorting and filtering?

Comment: [How to Work with Dates Before 1900 in Excel](http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/earlydates.htm)

Comment: @DavidPostill  I think `claws` is interested in **years** rather than true Excel dates.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Yes, but a year can be considered as 01 Jan, then it is  still a date and the link applies. "how can I reconcile precise dates and just years"

Answer (score 0):

Since EXCEL can only recognize as dates from 1900-01-01 to 9999-12-31, What I did without macros is the following:
a) I decided on a single calendar to use for the whole table. In my case was the proleptic Gregorian Calendar.
b) I use a single column TIME for dates entered as numbers in the following format for dates before the common era (BCE)
-YYYY.ssMMDD  where "-" means years before year 1 (or 0 if allowed), MM and DD are two digits for MONTH and DAY respectively, and the two ss digits allow sorting dates BCE; otherwise, months and days in those years will be understood in the wrong direction; for instance, January will be sorted as the youngest month, instead of the oldest one. Note that by putting the whole part of the number as years, I can use years earlier than -9999, the same for years above 9999.

For years belonging to the Common Era, I use:
YYYY.ssMMDD, with similar meaning as with the case of BCE dates. Since with positive numbers, the sorting would be correct even without the two ss digits, I can still use them for cases that I do not know the exact date, but I know the correct sequence.

Again, this is not an elegant solution but works for me, and it is quite practical for my needs. not that I wouldn't mind seeing if sometime EXCEL decides to extend the range of dates someday.